# JQuery selectors for first li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I need an onclick event, when the user clicks on the first li aka(Any Date).How do I select that element using jQuery?

```
<ul id="ui-id-1" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" role="menu" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-5">
   <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
    <a href="#">Any Date</a></li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
    <a href="#">Past 7 days</a></li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
    <a href="#">Past month</a></li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-5" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
    <a href="#">Past year</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use jquery [:first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector to target the 1st element in a collection of elements.

```
$('ul li:first').click(function()
{
   // do something 
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/3mb8ep19/

or jquery [first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) filter :

```
$('ul li').first().click(function()
{
   // do something
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/3mb8ep19/1/

Answer (score 1):

Well it has an `id` so you can use that in your selector. You are targeting the link inside the `li` correct?

```
$("#ui-id-2 a").click(function(){
 // function goes here

 return false; // the link itself has a behaviour associated with it so we want to stop that
});
```

Otherwise for something more generic you can use the :first-child selector.

> Note : While :first matches only a single element, the :first-child
>   selector can match more than one: one for each parent.

```
$("ul.ui-menu li:first-child a").click(function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**:first-child**](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

```js
$("ul.ui-menu li.ui-menu-item:first-child").on("click", function() {
  $(this).css("background", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ui-id-1" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content" role="menu" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-5">
  <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
    <a href="#">Any Date</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-3" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
    <a href="#">Past 7 days</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
    <a href="#">Past month</a>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-5" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">
    <a href="#">Past year</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the methods given below to select first li element.

**1. using jQuery :nth-child selector**
It selects the child of the element using its position. The value 1 select the li item located at first position.

```js
$( "ul li:nth-child(1)" ).click(function(){
  //do something here
 });
```

**2. using jQuery :first selector**
It selects the first li item.

```js
$( "ul li:first" ).click(function(){
  //do something here
 });
```

**3. using jQuery :eq() selector**
The li element starts with index 0. To select first item, you have use 0 as its value.

```js
$( "ul li:eq(0)" ).click(function(){
  //do something here
 });
```

See this: [Get the First Element of li Using jquery](https://tutorialdeep.com/knowhow/get-first-element-li-jquery/) for live examples.